# show message when all ng-repeat items have been exposed in DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am making a call that returns x number of results. I am ng-repeating through them and exposing 3 results at a time with a button click. When there are no more results to show, how can I capture that? I am using angular 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using Array.slice(start, numberOfItems) on your values and passing the result into your model.

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

$scope.values = []

$scope.clickedButton() {
    if (values.length > 0) {
         $scope.values = $scope.values.concat(values.splice(0,3))
    } else {
        $scope.message = 'No new stuff to show'
    }
}
```

the above clickedButton function would remove the first 3 values from the variable values and add it to the $scope.values property.  This would update your dom, so the ng-repeat would re-evaluate, if the array is empty you can display the message to your users

```
     <span ng-if="message.length > 0">{{ message }}</span>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="val in values">
           {{val}}
       </li>
     </ul>
```